# Get productinfo from Observer controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

Tags: magento2, event-observer, addtocart

In Magento 2:
I have created the event observer:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="orange_conditions" instance="Namespace\Name\Observer\RestrictAddToCart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In the observer execute method I would like to do the following:

**Access the information (object) from the product I have clicked on.**

To keep it simple: the SKU.
Later on I would like to have access to some other parameters. But first things first ...

**Below code is a start, but it is not working.** (found this in other questions)

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getDataByKey('product');

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        $item = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);

        $itemId = $item->getId();

        $this->_messageManager->addError($item);
        //set false if you not want to add product to cart
        $observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class RestrictAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * RestrictAddToCart constructor.
     *
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        try {
            $productId = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('product');
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
            $item = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
            if ($item) {
                $itemId = $item->getId();
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($item->getName());
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }

        //set false if you not want to add product to cart
        $observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `$item = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);`? This event is fired before adding it into the cart, so that could declare why $item is empty not? Or am I wrong? Using `$product->getSku()` is working ...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the product in your observer like this:

```
$product = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('product');
```

Comment: Changing this, and getting the $itemId is returning error ... `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on boolean`

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried and found out the below would sort you out:

```
$productId = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
```

Of course I allow myself to reuse part of the answer below and hook it to the line I advise you to use:

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    try {
       $productId = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
       $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
       /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
       $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
       /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
       $item = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
       if ($item) {
            $itemId = $item->getId();
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($item->getName());
       }
   }
    ..
```

good luck

Comment: why are you using the 'getControllerAction()'? @sohal-rana rule is working too?

Comment: If the below works, please discard my answer as it is clearly more complicated. My idea was that the dispatch process had a controller from which you get the request. I am surprised to hear the request is available directly at this part of the system